# DHCP lease not renewed upon expiration

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dhcp, ipv4

I'm a clueless newbie running Ubuntu 18 on top of VirtualBox on top of Windows 10 with a wireless connection to my ISP's router.  The VM's network adapter is set up in VB as bridged, and is configured in Ubuntu to use DHCP.  When I start my machine I get a 3600 second lease, but at the end the lease is not renewed unless I force it with "sudo dhclient", or if I bounce it in VB.

```
peter@peter-VirtualBox:~$ ip -4 address show dev enp0s3
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.0.26/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 1201sec preferred_lft 1201sec
```

I don't know if I should be looking for the problem in Ubuntu, VB, Windows, or the wireless router.  Any obvious clues?

Comment: I don't think there is a "problem" as such, the lease will automatically renew. See this reference for further info: https://sourcedaddy.com/networking/releasing-and-renewing-dhcp-settings.html

Comment: It doesn't renew.  After 3600 seconds it's gone and I have to force a renewal.  Also, the reference you gave is for Windows, but my Windows host is fine.  It's only the Ubuntu guest that is having problems.

Comment: Then view this resource: http://itfreetraining.com/dhcp/leases/ Will using a fixed ip address fix your issue - either in the DHCP server or the VB? You mentioned Windows in your OP hence the response which mentioned windoze...

Comment: Yes, I suppose I could grab a static address and solve the problem by brute force.  But I'm interested in getting to the bottom of the problem - my Ubuntu guest is the only system on the WLAN that seems to have this issue.  Where should I look?